# What hinders NetStream.onPeerConnect from being triggered?

Tags: apache-flex, p2p, soundcloud-stratus

I'm using Adobe Stratus (now renamed to Cirrus) to build a p2p application. Inside the application, I used **NetStream.onPeerConnect** callback function and expected it to be triggered every time when a peer is connected. However, it always failed with my friend A while strangely friend B managed to have the function called without any problem.

I was wondering what could be the cause to this issue?

Here are how the code pieces look like.

First of all, create a **NetConnection**.

```
netConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netConnectionHandler);
netConnection.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS+DEVELOPER_KEY);
```

Secondly, create **NetStream** upon NetConnection successfully connected.

```
private function netConnectionHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{

    switch (event.info.code){
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":

            sendStream = new NetStream(netConnection, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
            sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);

            var sendObj:Object = new Object();
            sendObj.onPeerConnect = function(subscriber:NetStream) : Boolean {

                trace("[onPeerConnect] far id: " + subscriber.farID);
                return true;
            } 
            sendStream.client = sendObj;
            sendStream.publish("file");
            ......
```

Thirdly, here's how I build the connection between two peers

```
    receivedStream = new NetStream(netConnection, farId);
    receivedStream.client = this;
    receivedStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, incomingStreamHandler);
    receivedStream.play("file");
```

Please help enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my friend A is behind a symmetric NAT. I'm thinking to setup a TURN server for us to build a successful connection.